# Node Plugin that tracks impressions and page views

Tags: node.js, npm, sequelize.js

Is there any Npm package that helps in inbuilt event tracking similar to [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem of ruby.

I want to track weekly events of user done on our website. I want to use it along with google analytics. so That I can log custom data in my system

I am using Sequelize as ORM

Comment: Not sure if you are exactly looking for it but winston worked well for me

Comment: it is more for the logging.

Comment: true but with little customization and using database to store logs you can use it like a tracker but then again not sure if you need something simple or more sophisticated

Answer (score 0):

You can use following libraries to track events:

- [track-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/track-event)
- [mixpanel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mixpanel)

Hope this helps.